# Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a neural network, from a `tf.data` data generator and a `tf.keras` model, as follows (a simplified version-because it would be too long):

`dataset = ...`

A `tf.data.Dataset` object that with the `next_x` method calls the `get_next` for the `x_train` iterator and for the `next_y` method calls the `get_next` for the `y_train` iterator. Each label is a `(1, 67)` array in one-hot form.

Layers:

```
input_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(240, 240, 3))  # dim of x
output = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input_tensor)
output= tf.keras.Dense(67, activation='softmax')(output)  # 67 is the number of classes
```

Model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=prediction)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), loss=tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(gen(dataset.next_x(), dataset.next_y()), steps_per_epochs=100)
```

`gen` is defined like this:

```
def gen(x, y):
    while True:
        yield(x, y)
```

My problem is that when I try to run it, I get an error in the `model.fit` part:

`ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.`

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: I have the same error. I am reading the tfrecords through the dataset api and pass the result to the model.fit method but it gives the same error as above. Did you figure out how to resolve this?

Comment: @user238607, what are the types and shapes of the records yielded by the dataset?

Comment: Would you share the functions that generate the data?

Comment: have you tried calling `next_x()` and `next_y()` inside your generator instead of calling it through arguments?

Comment: @DanielMöller : I have asked my question separately here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851793/valueerror-cannot-take-the-length-of-shape-with-unknown-rank  Could you take a look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. Actually I have to `run` next batch in a `tf.Session` before yielding it.
Here is how it works (I don't write the rest of the code, since it stays the same):

```
model.fit_generator(gen(), steps_per_epochs=100)

def gen():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        next_x = dataset.next_x()
        next_y = dataset.next_y()
        while True:
            x_batch = sess.run(next_x)
            y_batch = sess.run(next_y)
            yield x_batch, y_batch
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you post a longer stack-trace? I think your problem might be related to this recent tensorflow issue:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24520

There's also a simple PR that fixes it (not yet merged). Maybe try it out yourself?

**EDIT**

Here is the PR:
open `tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py`

replace the following (line 232 at the moment):

```
  if (x.shape is not None
      and len(x.shape) == 1
```

with this:

```
  if tensor_util.is_tensor(x):
    x_shape_ndims = x.shape.ndims if x.shape is not None else None
  else:
    x_shape_ndims = len(x.shape)

  if (x_shape_ndims == 1
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21777204)

Comment: Edited to include the PR changes

Answer (score 1):

For the issue `Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank`,
Thanks to above answer, I solved by add `output_shape` to from_generator according to this [issue comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24520#issuecomment-493787420).

In my case, I was using `Dataset.from_generator` for dataset pipeline.

Before:

```
Dataset.from_generator(_generator_factory, 
                       output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int8))
```

Working code for me:

```
Dataset.from_generator(_generator_factory, 
                       output_types = (tf.float32, tf.int8),
                       output_shapes = (
                           tf.TensorShape([2, 224, 224, 3]), 
                           tf.TensorShape([1,])
                       ))
```

Also found [this dataset official guide from tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators) indicates that:

> ...
>
> The `output_shapes` argument is not *required* but is highly recomended as many tensorflow operations **do not support tensors with unknown rank.** If the length of a particular axis is unknown or variable, set it as None in the output_shapes.
>
> ...