# ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to move our input pipelines to tensorflow dataset api. For that purpose, we have converted images and lables to tfrecords. We are then reading the tfrecords through the dataset api and comparing whether the initial data and the data read are same. So far so good. Below is the code that reads the tfrecords into the dataset

```
def _parse_function2(proto):

    # define your tfrecord again. Remember that you saved your image as a string.

    keys_to_features = {"im_path": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.string, allow_missing=True),
                        "im_shape": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
                        "score_shape": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
                        "geo_shape": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
                        "im_patches": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.string, allow_missing=True),
                        "score_patches": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.string, allow_missing=True),
                        "geo_patches": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.string, allow_missing=True),
                        }

    # Load one example
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=proto, features=keys_to_features)

    parsed_features['im_patches'] = parsed_features['im_patches'][0]
    parsed_features['score_patches'] = parsed_features['score_patches'][0]
    parsed_features['geo_patches'] = parsed_features['geo_patches'][0]

    parsed_features['im_patches'] = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['im_patches'], tf.uint8)
    parsed_features['im_patches'] = tf.reshape(parsed_features['im_patches'], parsed_features['im_shape'])

    parsed_features['score_patches'] = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['score_patches'], tf.uint8)
    parsed_features['score_patches'] = tf.reshape(parsed_features['score_patches'], parsed_features['score_shape'])

    parsed_features['geo_patches'] = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['geo_patches'], tf.int16)
    parsed_features['geo_patches'] = tf.reshape(parsed_features['geo_patches'], parsed_features['geo_shape'])

    return parsed_features['im_patches'], tf.cast(parsed_features["score_patches"],tf.int16), parsed_features["geo_patches"]



def create_dataset2(tfrecord_path):
    # This works with arrays as well
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([tfrecord_path], compression_type="ZLIB")

    # Maps the parser on every filepath in the array. You can set the number of parallel loaders here
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function2, num_parallel_calls=8)

    # This dataset will go on forever
    dataset = dataset.repeat()

    # Set the batchsize
    dataset = dataset.batch(1)

    return dataset
```

Now the dataset created by the above function is passed to the model.fit method as follows. I am following the [github gist](https://gist.github.com/datlife/abfe263803691a8864b7a2d4f87c4ab8) which gives an example of how to pass dataset into the model.fit

```
train_tfrecord = 'data/tfrecords/train/train.tfrecords'
test_tfrecord = 'data/tfrecords/test/test.tfrecords'

train_dataset  = create_dataset2(train_tfrecord)
test_dataset  = create_dataset2(test_tfrecord)


model.fit(
    train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator(),
    steps_per_epoch=5,
    epochs=10,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_data=test_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator(),
    callbacks=[function1, function2, function3],
    verbose=1)
```

But I am getting the error `ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.` at the model.fit function call above.

**EDIT 1 :** 
I am using the below code to iterate through the dataset and extract the rank and shape and types of the tensors.

```
train_tfrecord = 'data/tfrecords/train/train.tfrecords'

with tf.Graph().as_default():

    # Deserialize and report on the fake data
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([train_tfrecord], compression_type="ZLIB")
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function2)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()


    while True:
        try:
            next_element = iterator.get_next()
            im_patches, score_patches, geo_patches = next_element

            rank_im_shape = tf.rank(im_patches)
            rank_score_shape = tf.rank(score_patches)
            rank_geo_shape = tf.rank(geo_patches)


            shape_im_shape = tf.shape(im_patches)
            shape_score_shape = tf.shape(score_patches)
            shape_geo_shape = tf.shape(geo_patches)

            [ some_imshape, some_scoreshape, some_geoshape,\
             some_rank_im_shape, some_rank_score_shape, some_rank_geo_shape,
             some_shape_im_shape, some_shape_score_shape, some_shape_geo_shape] = \
                sess.run([ im_patches, score_patches, geo_patches,
                          rank_im_shape, rank_score_shape, rank_geo_shape,
                          shape_im_shape, shape_score_shape, shape_geo_shape])



            print("Rank of the 3 patches ")
            print(some_rank_im_shape)
            print(some_rank_score_shape)
            print(some_rank_geo_shape)

            print("Shapes of the 3 patches ")
            print(some_shape_im_shape)
            print(some_shape_score_shape)
            print(some_shape_geo_shape)

            print("Types of the 3 patches ")
            print(type(im_patches))
            print(type(score_patches))
            print(type(geo_patches))

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

Below is the output of those 2 tfrecords.

```
Rank of the 3 patches 
4
4
4
Shapes of the 3 patches 
[   1 3553 2529    3]
[   1 3553 2529    2]
[   1 3553 2529    5]
Types of the 3 patches 
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
Rank of the 3 patches 
4
4
4
Shapes of the 3 patches 
[   1 3553 5025    3]
[   1 3553 5025    2]
[   1 3553 5025    5]
Types of the 3 patches 
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

One thing I did realize is that if I try to return mulitple labels as a list and compare the returned values from the above iterator script, I get the error

```
def _parse_function2(proto):

    ---- everything same as above ----
    ---- just returning the labels as list---


    return parsed_features['im_patches'], [tf.cast(parsed_features["score_patches"],tf.int16), parsed_features["geo_patches"]]
```

Capturing the above returned values as :

```
    while True:
        try:
            next_element = iterator.get_next()
            im_patches, [score_patches, geo_patches] = next_element
```

Error is as follows : `TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`

EDIT 2 : Here's the definition of the fit function. It seems it can take tensorflow `tensors` as well as `steps_per_epoch`

```
def fit(self,
      x=None,
      y=None,
      batch_size=None,
      epochs=1,
      verbose=1,
      callbacks=None,
      validation_split=0.,
      validation_data=None,
      shuffle=True,
      class_weight=None,
      sample_weight=None,
      initial_epoch=0,
      steps_per_epoch=None,
      validation_steps=None,
      max_queue_size=10,
      workers=1,
      use_multiprocessing=False,
      **kwargs):
"""Trains the model for a fixed number of epochs (iterations on a dataset).

Arguments:
    x: Input data. It could be:
      - A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays
        (in case the model has multiple inputs).
      - A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors
        (in case the model has multiple inputs).
      - A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors,
        if the model has named inputs.
      - A `tf.data` dataset or a dataset iterator. Should return a tuple
        of either `(inputs, targets)` or
        `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`.
      - A generator or `keras.utils.Sequence` returning `(inputs, targets)`
        or `(inputs, targets, sample weights)`.
    y: Target data. Like the input data `x`,
      it could be either Numpy array(s) or TensorFlow tensor(s).
      It should be consistent with `x` (you cannot have Numpy inputs and
      tensor targets, or inversely). If `x` is a dataset, dataset
      iterator, generator, or `keras.utils.Sequence` instance, `y` should
      not be specified (since targets will be obtained from `x`).
```

Comment: Does the iterator outputs numpy arrays with defined shapes? Please print type and shape of each output of the iterator.

Comment: @DanielMöller : I have added more details to the question. Could you take a look?

Comment: Ok... a generator for Keras cannot receive tensors. They must receive numpy arrays.

Comment: @DanielMöller : But if you look at the gist I am following : https://gist.github.com/datlife/abfe263803691a8864b7a2d4f87c4ab8  It is directly feeding the dataset iterator to the model without any conversion of tensor to numpy arrays. Is that not possible ?

Comment: @DanielMöller : Is this question relevant to my issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184863/how-do-you-make-tensorflow-keras-fast-with-a-tfrecord-dataset

Comment: I'm confused about that gist... `fit` should not take `steps_per_epoch` nor iterators. The only method that accepts generators is `fit_generator`. Which makes me thing this example might be flawed.

Comment: @DanielMöller : I have posted the definition of fit function. According to the definition, it should be able to take `tensor` as input as well as `steps_per_epoch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in tensorflow.keras module. A fix which works has been suggested in the github issue below.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24520